# Does IBM Bluemix eliminate the need to maintain servers?

Tags: ibm-cloud, continuous-deployment

Currently we are maintaining server for each environment like DEV, FVT, UAT and PROD.
I think we can create spaces in Bluemix to replicate the above setup, but does Bluemix completely remove the need of servers?.
I think we at least need to maintain a Sandbox environment to test the code before pushing it to Bluemix. 
And how does the deployment process differ in Bluemix compared to the traditional way?

Answer (score 2):

@aryanRaj_kary

The concept of spaces[1] is perfect for separating out environments like DEV, FVT & PROD. I don't think there's anything wrong with having a sandbox as well, but the spaces concept in Bluemix should satisfy your needs.

In Bluemix, in terms of HA, you have the choice of two deployment methods. We use an intelligent update service called Active Deploy [2] and we also employ the zero-downtime concept of "Blue-green" deployments [3].  The difference between the two is that in Blue-Green deployments, both versions are never active at the same time.  However, with Active Deploy, there's minimal traffic allowed to both versions during ramp-up phase [4].

[1] https://console.ng.bluemix.net/docs/admin/orgs_spaces.html#spaceinfo

[2] https://console.ng.bluemix.net/docs/services/ActiveDeploy/index.html

[3] https://console.ng.bluemix.net/docs/manageapps/updapps.html#blue_green

[4] https://console.ng.bluemix.net/docs/services/ActiveDeploy/faq.html#bluegreendeployments

Comment: @RandalAnders- thank you for the info. If we want to use tools like Urban Code to do the deployments, we would need to have one more server, right?

Comment: Correct, you would need one more server for UCD.  It would look something like this:

https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/blogs/hickmat/resource/BLOGS_UPLOADED_IMAGES/BluemixandUCD.jpeg?lang=en